# Polymorphic Callback Implementation

Tags: c++, delegates, polymorphism

I am using Component Based Architecture in my application. I'm at the stage where I need to allow a `Component` to specify a callback that will be executed upon an event.

```
typedef void(Component::*EventCallback) ();
typedef std::pair<Component*, EventCallback> EventDelegate;
```

The problem with the above type definition is that all components inherit from `Component` but will never be a direct `Component`. So the following line of code is not valid:

```
MoveComponent* mc = new MoveComponent(); // inherits from Component
EventDelegate ed(mc , &MoveComponent::moveToXY); // Compiler error here: expects Component* not MoveComponent*, and same for EventCallback.
```

Any ideas how I can achieve a 'Polymorphic' callback? Or any other design/implementation advice?

Example usage:

```
typedef void(Component::*EventCallback) ();
typedef std::pair<Component*, EventCallback> EventDelegate;

class Component {
    // ...
};

class MoveComponent : public Component {
public:
    MoveComponent() {

        EventDelegate ed(this, &MoveComponent::moveToXY);
        ComponentManager::registerEvent(ed);
    }

    void moveToXY() { }
};

class ComponentManager {
public:

    static void registerEvent(EventDelegate ed) {
        evtRegistry.push_back(ed);
    }

    static void runEvent(EventDelegate ed) {
        for (int i=0; i<evtRegistry.size(); i++) {
            Component* context = evtRegistry.at(i).first;
            EventCallback ec = evtRegistry.at(i).second;
            context->*ec();
        }
    }

private:
    static std::vector <EventDelegate> evtRegistry;
};
```

Comment: std::function. Delegates are so last decade!

Answer (score 6):

```
using EventDeligate = std::function<void()>;

auto cp = std::make_shared<MoveComponent>();
auto ed = EventDeligate([cp](){ cp.moveToXY(); });
```

To do it your way, `Component` must have a (possibly pure) virtual function `moveToXY`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is a hobby project, so it would be nice to tackle the problem without using `std::function` if possible.

Comment: That would be pretty darn silly.  Being a hobby project I'd expect you'd want to use all the tools at your disposal.  Why learn the way we DON'T do it anymore?